# Add a link near aged away flag to reflag it again

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, aged-away

It will be very convenient if we can reflag aged away flag (after 14 days of course) just via one click. For example it can be like this:

[image: reflaging aged away flag]

Comment: Not sure if it's worth it. If the flag aged away once, it will most likely age away again.

Comment: @Floern Worth it or not it's another story. The issues are (when I try to reflag): 1) I have to repeat this actions, 2) I don't actually know immediately if 14 days are over and I have to calculate days or try reflaging.

Answer (score 5):

There is no benefit to this feature other than making it easier for users to continually flag things over and over. If you care enough about the flag, then you should *need* to prove that by going through all the steps again. We are not adding a one-click reflag button.